# Sending Mail With Plesk Server

Tags: laravel, plesk

I made an application who send many emails for different actions, i tested with Mailtrap.io. Everything is going well with this test service but when i tried to migrate the the real smtp from my domain. Nothing happen.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mydomain.eu
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

When i put MAIL_PORT = 25 i have no exception but any mails is send. When i put the port 565 i get

> Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.mydomain.eu [Connection refused #111]

If i put the username and password from the mail adresse i configured in the plesk it's change nothing.

The serveur use SSH maybe the error comes from this ?

Hope someone could help me .. thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

port "565" ? Pls. make sure, that the actual used port in your script is actually the one you would like to connect to!

```
#25 smtp (TCP)
#110 pop3 (TCP)
#143 imap (TCP)

#465 smtps (TCP)
#993 imaps (TCP)
#995 pop3s (TCP)

AND

#587 mail message submission (TCP)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is port 587 with ssl encryption,

But you must active port 587 in your plesk domein.

You must check the option "Enable SMTP on port 587 for all IP addresses" Then you can send mail from port 587.

The check option is location in your default mail settings, not your domein settings.